# Real and Apparent Depth

Tags: geometric-optics

Why can't human eyes see bent light rays ? In real/apparent depth why do we think light is coming straight?

Answer (score 1):

Light does not carry information about the curvature of the path it has taken, so your eyes and brain have no information to process about the bending. They know the final direction, the intensity, and the frequency.